# ASIHTTPRequest POST method gets executed twice

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am trying to download some data from server , using `ASIHTTPRequest` , but for no reason the method in which this code resides gets executed two times, here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [viewDisabled setHidden:FALSE];
        [activityBusy startAnimating];
        [self downloadData];

        [viewDisabled setHidden:TRUE];
        [activityBusy stopAnimating];
}
-(void) downloadData
{
    // download ingredients
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://im.com/wrapper/wrapperSL.svc/downloaddata"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // create JSON input body
    NSMutableString *json = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger langId = [defs integerForKey:@"language"];

    [json appendFormat:@"{\"LanguageId\":\"%d\"}",langId];

    NSLog(json);

    // init request and call
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    // [request setDelegate:self];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; encoding=utf-8"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    [request appendPostData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO;

    [request startSynchronous];


    NSString *response;

    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) {
        response = [request responseString];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Downloading App data failed!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }
}
```

Somehow the request gets sent twice intact **the method itself gets executed twice** and I receive data twice.

Please suggest a solution

Comment: you commented both calls to `downloadData`, each of them was executing request twice ? show where you call method `downloadData` to make sure you are not calling it twice without even knowing it, also, you can put a break point in first line of the method and look at stacktrace to see why it is called twice

Comment: it was a mistake in posting code now have edited it the actual code

Comment: Are you forced to use ASIHTTPRequest? I mean, that lib was abandoned long ago by it's lead developer. For something similar try AFNetworking

Comment: I would also recommend to go for AFNetworking if only it is possible. Are you 100% sure that `downloadData` is not called somewhere else for example `viewDidAppear`??

Comment: Also are you sure about doing it synchronously and blocking main thread?

Comment: Yes I am forced to use this as this is old app and huge code relying on ASIHTTP , I have called it at only one place and i tried it calling in background as well, just to make sure I m now calling an blocking main thread but situation is same